# When copying directories with sudo it copies just the first level of its hierarchy

Tags: bash, sudo

This question was also asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825246).

When I copy some directory (dir) recursively with sudo in bash it copies just the first level of the dir hierarchy, but when used without sudo it copies the dir with all its subdirs, though commands in command-line have the difference only in the presence of sudo.

Why does this happen?

For example:

```
k@l:/$ tree
.
|
|__a
|  |
|  |__b
|     | 
|     |__1.htm   
|
|__c
k@l:/$ sudo cp -r /a/b /c/d
k@l:/$ cd /c
k@l:/c$ ls
d
k@l:/c$ cd d
bash: cd: /c/d: Permission denied
k@l:/c$ tree
.
|__d [error opening dir]

1 directory, 0 files
```

Comment: There are error messages on your listing. You perhaps want to learn their meaning first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `sudo cp -r /a/b /c/d` the folder are copied to `/c/d/` as root with root as the owner, therefore you get a **Permission Denied** since you need root permission to open the directory, try opening `/c/d/` in a Root Terminal; alternatively, you need to alter the file owner or fix the permission by using `chown`/`chmod` so your current user will be able to access the folder.

Note: `sudo cd` won't work since `cd` is a shell command, not programs.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe /c/d had permissions 700 with a different owner. Try `sudo chmod -R 755 /c/d`.

Comment: +1: Or you could try '`sudo chown -R me /c/d`'.

Comment: Yup, that'd work too.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather use `cp -a` instead of `cp -r`. The latter might not preserve some file attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the `cp` command, you could run `sudo` as a specific user doing something like

```
sudo -u thisUser cp -r /a/b /c/d
```

Nevertheless, this will work only if `thisUser` has permissions for `/a/b`